# Why the book says JDBC damage the Parental delegation model？

Tags: java, jdbc, jvm, classloader

Some books say JDBC damage the Parental delegation model, but i read the source about JDBC not found where the breaking shows.

it seems like every class is loaded by Application Classloader：

```
public static void doingJdbc(){
    try {

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/design", "root", "fengcs");

        String sql = "select * from tb_user";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getResultSet();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int id = resultSet.getInt(1);
            System.out.println("===================>"+ id);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In DriverManager also not found the breaking, i don't know where the code shows the breaking.

please show me the specific code, Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "damage the Parental delegation model"? Can you please clarify

Comment: "some books" is not a title I know, can't say in which context that really vague statement was made.

Comment: Java SPI operating will damage the Parental delegation model，parent classloader will delegate son classloader to load a class，but i think is not need to do this, when i need a connection,i usually use main method to get connection,it is loaded by application classloader,then every class can obtain this app classloader.

Comment: The question is really unclear. In a Java EE environment, classloading and the delegation rules depend on the application server. Which book are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

It does break the Parental delegation model.

*The delegation model requires that any request for a class loader to load a given class is first delegated to its parent class loader before the requested class loader tries to load the class itself.*

So by the delegation model, the java.sql.Connection in your code snippet is supposed to be passed to the BootStrap Classloader(root classloader) by the System Classloader(aka Application classloader), and the BootStrap Classloader will try to load it. And it can be loaded.

try:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Connection.class.getClassLoader());
    }
```

The output is null, which means it's loaded by the root classloader.

But if you do this

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/foo", "username", "password");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(connection.getClass().getClassLoader());
    }
```

The output is sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2 or something like it, meanning it's loaded by System classloader(Application Classloader).

So we demonstrated that root classloader is able to load java.sql.Connection, but is instead loaded by its children class, the System classloader. And this, is a breach of the delegation model according to its definition.

Then it comes to the question of *How*, and *Why*?

As for How, the trick is inside the DriverManager class.

from javadoc

```
 private static Connection getConnection(
        String url, java.util.Properties info, Class<?> caller) throws SQLException {

        // ...

        ClassLoader callerCL = caller != null ? caller.getClassLoader() : null;

                callerCL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();



       // ...

        for(DriverInfo aDriver : registeredDrivers) {
            if(isDriverAllowed(aDriver.driver, callerCL)) {
                try {
                    // ...

                    Connection con = aDriver.driver.connect(url, info);

                   // ...
                        return con;
                    }
```

It tries to get the classloader from the current thread, which usually is the System classloader. And use it to load the database driver implementaion and return the connection object.

Or simply put, the parent classloader trys to use the child classloader to load some classes! According to parent delegation, the parent classloader shouldn't even be aware of the existence of the child classloader.

Then comes to the question of Why would Sun/Oracle do this?

Classes loaded by two different classloaders can't have access to each other. So the java.sql.Connection class and its implementation has to be loaded by the same classloader to work.
Then we can either
1) Load both the java.sql.Connection and its implementation classes offered by specific database vendors by Bootstrap classloader.
or
2) Load both of them by System classloader.

The first option is not possible here, becasue we know Bootstrap classloader loads classes from rt.jar. It doesn't load classes from your classpath.

The second option is against the Parent Delegation model, so the model is breached here. This breach is still controversial and some people consider it a bad design.

Comment: but the class of Connection is "com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection", which is provided by mysql-java-connector jar. Therefore, an AppClassLoader loads a third part Class. So I think there is no break of Parent-Delegation-Model.